# passing method reference in object and calling it raising the problem , the constructor inject dependency coming as undeifined

Tags: angular

here the link for the stackblits [stackBlits Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8dsrxy?file=src/app/app.component.html)
here i created the array and passed the method reference in the object of array but i getting undefined for the constructor injected property

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    alert(http);
  }

  PrintTwo() {
    alert(this.http);
    alert('two');
  }
  btns: Array<any> = [
    {
      name: 'two',
      title: 'two',
      functionToCall: this.PrintTwo,
      class: 'btn-danger',
    },
  ];
}
```

here is HTML part

```
  <ng-container *ngFor="let btn of btns">
  <button
    class="btn me-4 {{ btn.class }}"
    [title]="btn.title"
    #btnElement
    (click)="btn.functionToCall()">
    {{ btn.name }}
  </button>
</ng-container>
```

here from constructor in alert object is coming but when calling from a method it is coming as undefined

i dont know why it behaving like this , i think when i am passing the method whole complete method is passed and there is no other properties means it does not taking class method as refrence all it is doing taking method code directly in method

Comment: You need to `bind` the method to `this`, or use arrow function syntax for the method definition instead.

Comment: how i am not getting can you give example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `btn.functionToCall()` is called in the context of `btn`. It means that `this` points to:

```
{
  name: 'two',
  title: 'two',
  functionToCall: this.PrintTwo,
  class: 'btn-danger',
}
```

Try to bind the `PrintTwo` to the correct context:

```
{
  name: 'two',
  title: 'two',
  functionToCall: this.PrintTwo.bind(this),
  class: 'btn-danger',
}
```

Comment: thank you it really help me out in this big Problem